# bug in comparison

Tags: c#, if-statement, comparison

I have the following code:

```
decimal xtop = 2.0m, xbot = -2.0m, ytop = 2.0m, ybot = -2.0m, checkx, checky;
string inputx, inputy; 
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input number x:");
    inputx = Console.ReadLine();
    if (decimal.TryParse(inputx, out xtop))
    {
        checkx = decimal.Parse(inputx);
        Console.WriteLine("Input number y:");
        inputy = Console.ReadLine();

        if (decimal.TryParse(inputy, out xtop))
        {
            checky = decimal.Parse(inputy);
            checky = 0.5m;
            if (checkx >= xbot && checkx <= xtop && checky >= ybot && checky <= ytop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The input is inside the rectangle");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The input is outside the rectangle");
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

If the inputs from the console are: x = 1 and y = 0,5 I get the following bug.
As you can see, both numbers are in the limits needed to print the true value. However, I get the false value anyway. This happens if the values are in double as well. Can someone explain why does this happen ?

Comment: If you change `0,5` to `0.5`, it works for me. `The input is inside the circle`. Also, this checks if you're inside a rectangle, not a circle.

Comment: This code checks whether the input is within a rectangle, not a circle.

Comment: The problem is not the check but the conversion from string to double, but you don't show us the relevant code, i.e. the conversion code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning the value of `xtop` twice when you use it as the `out` argument for `TryParse`. The second time you put it as the `out` argument is where it becomes `0.5` and so `checkx <= xtop` becomes false.

```
if (decimal.TryParse(inputy, out xtop))
```

When you use `out` it means that you are going to assign that value.

Comment: Wow, that really did the job. Thank you. Guess I should read thoroughly enough when I learn about the different methods, values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you use commas where I use decimal points, but isnt checky supposed to be
set to 0.5 and not 0,5?
On my compiler if I set checky = 0.5 the program prints
The input is in the circle.
Which is reasonable apart from the fact that it's a test for being inside a square.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the correct culture when parsing the number:

```
var myCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); // Adapt to your culture;
if (Decimal.TryParse(inputx, NumberStyles.Float, myCulture, out checkx)) {
    ...
}
```

And you are also parsing four times. Review your logic!